# XSD for recursive element definition

Tags: xml, xsd

**I have a case where I need an element to able to either nest itself or have other elements.**

Something like this should be valid:

```
<root>
  <rule condition="...">
    <rule condition="...">
      <setting>...</setting>
    </rule>
  </rule>
  <rule condition="...">
    <setting>...</setting>
  </rule>
</root>
```

But this should **not** be valid:

```
<root>
  <rule condition="...">
    <rule condition="...">
      <setting>...</setting>
    </rule>
    <setting>...</setting>
    <setting>...</setting>
  </rule>
</root>
```

If I understand XSD correctly this should do the job but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
<xs:complexType name="RuleType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="rule" minOccurs="1" 
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" type="RuleType" />
        <xs:element name="setting" minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="condition" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSD will allow your first example XML but not your second:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="rule" type="RuleType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="RuleType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="setting" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element ref="rule" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="condition" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**Read the XSD like this:**  *Each `rule` can consist of either one or more `setting` elements or one or more other `rule` elements (recursively).*